# Constructor String returns 'File does not exist' error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I am trying to build a SharePoint 2010 web part which includes a user control called "ChartUserControl.ascx". I understand this file needs to be loaded into the webpart with the syntax:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()\
{
    Control control = Page.LoadControl(_ascxPath);
}
```

... where "_ascxPath" is a previously defined string referencing the location of my user control file within the Sharepoint filesystem. So, after deploying my project, I did a file search for ChartUserControl.ascx and found it at "14\TEMPLATE\UpdatePanelTest".

This means my _ascxPath string should be something like one of the following:

```
private const string _ascxPath = @"~/UpdatePanelTest/ChartUserControl.ascx";

//or

private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_UpdatePanelTest/ChartUserControl.ascx";

//or

private const string _ascxPath = @"~/TEMPLATE/UpdatePanelTest/ChartUserControl.ascx";

//or

private const string _ascxPath = @"~/_TEMPLATE/UpdatePanelTest/ChartUserControl.ascx";
```

But all of these possibilities return a "file does not exist" error at runtime. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Server.MapPath` as the `LoadControl` requires an server path, not a virtual directory path.